# Alignment of TikZ pictures in subfigures

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have made two figures using TikZ that I would like to place side by side. This is done in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subbottom[Convex set]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rotate=-45,fill=gray!30] (0,0) ellipse (30pt and 45pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\hspace{1cm}
\subbottom[Non-convex set]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=gray!30] (0,0) to [out=140,in=90] (-1,-1)
    to [out=-90,in=240] (0.8,-0.6)
    to [out=60,in=-60] (1.2,1.2)
    to [out=120,in=90] (0.3,0.7)
    to [out=-90,in=20] (0.3,0)
    to [out=200,in=-40] (0,0);
    \draw (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0.7,0.7);
    \fill (-0.5,-0.5) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \fill (0.7,0.7) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Graphical interpretation of convex sets.}
\label{fig:convexSet}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which results in:
[image: convexSet]

The problem is that neither the top, center, or bottom of the subfigures are aligned. How is this resolved? And what causes this misalignment? A faulty use of the TikZ coordinate system?

Comment: Try to add the option `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,remember picture]` for both tikzpictures

Comment: The size of your figures are different in different directions from origo. Drawing the `help lines` helps (pun intended), as you give both pictures dimensions from `(-2,-2)` to `(2,2)`. If you don't want them, an easy solution can be to add `\path (-2,-2) grid (2,2);` to both pictures. But there's bound to be a more elegant way, I believe.

Comment: @JMP It does not work, since your solution messes with the alignment of the captions.

Comment: @Holene Thanks for the solution. It requires some messy estimation of the vertical spacing, but it work. As you say, a more elegant solution probably exists, which is still desired.

Comment: @Thomas do you mind if I use your code in a publicly posted document?

Comment: @Nitin: Not at all. Go ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the `to` paths use some control points that extend the bounding box of the second figure. You can see this by adding `\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);` at the end of each `tikzpicture`, which gives you this:

[image]

As you can see there is some extra whitespace around the second one. I don't know of an automatic fix for this, but you can set the bounding box manually with `\useasboundingbox`:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subbottom[Convex set]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rotate=-45,fill=gray!30] (0,0) ellipse (30pt and 45pt);
    %\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\hspace{1cm}
\subbottom[Non-convex set]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-1,-1.35) rectangle (1.5,1.35); % values found by trial and error
    \draw[fill=gray!30] (0,0) to [out=140,in=90] (-1,-1)
    to [out=-90,in=240] (0.8,-0.6)
    to [out=60,in=-60] (1.2,1.2)
    to [out=120,in=90] (0.3,0.7)
    to [out=-90,in=20] (0.3,0)
    to [out=200,in=-40] (0,0);
    \draw (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0.7,0.7);
    \fill (-0.5,-0.5) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \fill (0.7,0.7) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    %\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Graphical interpretation of convex sets.}
\label{fig:convexSet}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind if I use this code in a publicly posted document?

Comment: @Nitin In general, all code on the site is published under a Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike license (http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/licensing), so you are free to reuse it under the terms of that license. For my contribution, go right ahead.