# Drawing a set with a particular shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-calc

I would like to draw a non-convex set as in the following image and I like to start from my MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\coordinate (A) at (0,2);
\coordinate (B) at (4.5,0);

\draw (A)--(B) node[anchor=north west] {\small $p'x=\alpha$} coordinate[midway] (M) coordinate[pos=0.85](k);

\draw[-latex] (M) node[dot=above left:$x_{0}$] at (M) {} --($(M)!2cm!90:(B)$) node[anchor=north west]{$p$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe something like that could turn out to be useful, but I don't know how this syntax works (this is from > [Alignment of TikZ pictures in subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302589/alignment-of-tikz-pictures-in-subfigures))

```
 \draw[fill=gray!30] (0,0) to [out=140,in=90] (-1,-1) node[anchor=south west]{$A$}
    to [out=-90,in=240] (0.8,-0.6)
    to [out=60,in=-60] (1.2,1.2)
    to [out=120,in=90] (0.3,0.7)
    to [out=-90,in=20] (0.3,0)
    to [out=200,in=-40] (0,0);

    \draw (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0.7,0.7);
    \fill (-0.5,-0.5) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \fill (0.7,0.7) circle[radius=1.5pt];
```

Comment: The syntax is very simple: `in` is the angle of the ingoing path, and `out` the one of the outgoing. if you ensure that the next `out` and the `previous` differ by `180`, the path won't have corners, i.e. look smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\coordinate (A) at (0,2);
\coordinate (B) at (4.5,0);

\draw (A)--(B) node[anchor=north west] {\small $p'x=\alpha$} coordinate[midway] (M) coordinate[pos=0.85](k);

\draw[-latex] (M) node[dot=above left:$x_{0}$] at (M) {} --($(M)!2cm!90:(B)$) node[anchor=north west]{$p$};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myslope}{atan2(2,-4.5)}
\draw[fill=gray!30] (M) to[out=\myslope,in=0] ++ (-2,0.5) to[out=180,in=90] ++ (-1,-0.5)
 to[out=-90,in=90] ++ (2,-2) to[out=-90,in=90] ++ (-3,-1)
 to[out=-90,in=180] ++(4,-1) to[out=0,in=\myslope+180] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]